# Is F.D.C. Willard's second helium paper available online?

Tags: specific-reference

I am curious to read F.D.C. Willard's second paper on the structure of solid helium 3,

> F.D.C. Willard. L’hélium 3 solide: un antiferromagnétique nucléaire. *La Recherche* **114** (septembre 1980).

Unfortunately, [the *La Recherche* site catalog](http://sciences.gloubik.info//spip.php?article528) only offers a list of titles and no indication of where one can obtain a copy. (Googling, of course, yielded no usable links among many incidental mentions in pages praising Willard's achievements.) Inter-library loan could in principle work, but Worldcat informs me that the nearest library with any copies of the journal is in Denmark. Is there a pdf floating somewhere online? His other paper is open access in his honour, so I'm hoping that this one is also obtainable in some way.

Comment: That website is not the official website of the journal. Thus, I'd write to the author of that website, [who seems passionate](http://sciences.gloubik.info/spip.php?auteur1) about that journal if he can scan you a copy. He might be pleased that his work could be useful to someone.

Comment: Note that ILL for journal articles usually involves scanning and sending a PDF, so Denmark isn't as far from you ask you think.